# Rounding Decimal with no precision

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, rounding

I want to round this decimal number `14999994` to this value `15000000`, but `Math.Round()` doesn't work for me!

Please notice that my decimal number doesn't have any precision

Comment: how should the number 1410000 be rounded? down or up?

Comment: 14999994 to 15000000

Comment: divide, round, multiply

Comment: Could you add some other examples of the output expected? For example what for 0.23 or for 14432100.45?

Comment: it should be 14432100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static double RoundToSignificantDigits(double d, int digits)
{
    if (d == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    double scale = Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d))) + 1 - digits);
    return Math.Sign(d) * scale * Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs(d) / scale);
}
```

It's based on calculating a "scale" based on the `Math.Log10` (but note that `Math.Abs` for the negative numbers!), minus the digits precision given, then dividing the number by this "scale", rounding and re-multiplying by this "scale". Note even the use of `Math.Sign`: we round up (`Math.Ceiling`) the absolute value of `d` and then "reattach" the sign.

Use it like:

```
double n = RoundToSignificantDigits(14999994, 2); // 15000000
```

Note that `double` are an ugly beast:

```
double num = 0.2;
num += 0.1; // 0.30000000000000004

double num2 = RoundToSignificantDigits(num, 1); // 0.4
```

Comment: hey bro my number is variable and not static 14999994 is just a example !

Comment: I asked you: *how should the number 1410000 be rounded? down or up?* you responded *14999994 to 15000000*